# Prisma bulk update items with different data

Tags: javascript, prisma

I need to update some fields, but each item should be updated with different value:

```js
await prisma.tokens.updateMany({
    where: {
        product_id: "123",
      },
      data: {
        contract_address: '0x123456',
        mint_edition: i, // <- `i` should be taken from a loop
      },
})
```

Is there a way to update many items each with different data?

Comment: Maybe the $transaction api is what you are looking for: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/transactions

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no such functionality, what I would do is splitting it up into 2 separate steps. First, I would get all tokens with `getAll({ where: {} })` and then loop over each token and update one at a time with the index from the loop. If you want to make sure that either all tokens update or none, you can wrap everything within a [transaction](https://prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/transactions)